# I made a Simple Score Game in C# Console

Tags: c#, game, console, visual-studio

I've created a simple score game. The goal is improving my knowledge about OOP.

This is my `Main` method:

```
using System;

namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Process.UI();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's very simple and just calls a method named `UI`.

This is my `Snake` method (I named it `Snake` because it's like a snake game):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Snake
{
    class Snake
    {
        static int headOfSnake;
        public static int Score { get; set; }

        public static void GenericRandomCircle()
        {
            Random test = new Random();
            int index = test.Next(Process.ListOfDots.Count);
            Process.ListOfDots[index] = '■';
        }

        public static void PositionOfSnake()
        {
            Random test = new Random();
            headOfSnake = test.Next(Process.ListOfDots.Count);
            Process.ListOfDots[headOfSnake] = '▒';
        }

        public static void Move(string move, int Step)
        {
            switch (move)
            {
                case "w":
                    ChangeSnakePosition(Step, -20);
                    break;

                case "s":
                    ChangeSnakePosition(Step, 20);
                    break;

                case "a":
                    ChangeSnakePosition(Step, -1);
                    break;

                case "d":
                    ChangeSnakePosition(Step, 1);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void ChangeSnakePosition(int Step, int WhereToWhere)
        {
            try
            {
                int Counter = headOfSnake;
                for (int i = 0; i < Step; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    if (Process.ListOfDots[Counter + WhereToWhere] == '■')
                    {
                        Score++;
                        GenericRandomCircle();
                    }
                    Process.ListOfDots[Counter] = '∙';
                    Counter = Counter + WhereToWhere;
                    Process.ListOfDots[Counter] = '▒';
                    RefreshGameBoard();
                }
                headOfSnake = Counter;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                RefreshGameBoard();
                Console.WriteLine("YOU LOSE!!! START GAME AGAIN");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        static void RefreshGameBoard()
        {
            Process.GameBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the last class called `Process` to process the game:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Snake
{
    class Process
    {
        static List<char> _listOfDots = new List<char>();
        static bool isGenerate;
        static string userMove;
        static int userStep;

        public static List<char> ListOfDots
        {
            get { return _listOfDots; }
            set { _listOfDots = value; }
        }

        public static void GameBoard()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗");
            for (int i = 0; i < ListOfDots.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 20 == 0 && i == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("║ {0} ", ListOfDots[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                else if (i % 20 == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("║\n║ {0} ", ListOfDots[i]);
                    continue;
                }

                Console.Write("{0} ", ListOfDots[i]);

                if (i == ListOfDots.Count - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("║");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public static void ShowGuide()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Score: {0}", Snake.Score);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("up: W \t down: S \t right: D \t left: A");
        }

        public static void UI()
        {
            if (!isGenerate)
            {
                FirstGenerate();
            }
            MoveChecks("Enter W S D A", "Put numbers");
            Snake.Move(userMove, userStep);
        }

        static void MoveChecks(string wasdMessage, string stepMessage)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                GameBoard();
                ShowGuide();
                userMove = GetString("Enter W S D A to move: ");
                if (userMove != "w" && userMove != "a" && userMove != "s" && userMove != "d")
                {
                    GetError(String.Format("▌ {0} ▐", wasdMessage));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    userStep = Convert.ToInt32(GetString("How Many Step: "));
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    GetError(String.Format("▌ {0} ▐", stepMessage));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        static void FirstGenerate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string userInput = GetString("Please Enter a number can be divided by 100 to play the game (less than 400) :");
                if (ListOfDots.Count > 0)
                {
                    GetError("You Can't Insert to the BoardGame.");
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(userInput) % 100 == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(userInput) <= 400)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(userInput); i++)
                        {
                            ListOfDots.Add('∙');
                        }

                        Snake.GenericRandomCircle();
                        Snake.PositionOfSnake();
                        GameBoard();
                        Snake.Score = 0;
                        isGenerate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GetError("Please Enter a number divided by 100 and less than 400.");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                }
            }
        }

        // STATIC METHODS - Once Write * EveryWhere Use.
        public static string GetString(string message)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.Write(message.ToLower());
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            return Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void GetError(string message)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
}
```

How do you think this program can be made more object-oriented and expanded?
Please tell me the problems of this program so that I can improve my knowledge.
Thanks.

Comment: I was busy writing an answer and realized that I was drifting far from the topic. I decided to rather post my solution as a new [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269591/c-console-snake-game). No offence meant and I liked the way you formatted the output =)

Comment: @upkajdt No problem my friend. I will learn a lot from your code.

Comment: Cool! When you create games it is always good to split your concerns into `GameState`, `Rendering`, `HandleUserInput`, `UpdateState`, and `StateEvaluation`. A good exercise would be to take my code and see if you can add internal walls or a computer-based snake opponent. Next step, console-based PacMan / Astroids =). Please let me know if you have any questions about my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few tips:

1. `Process` name is conflicting with `System.Diagnostics.Process` the conflict may appear in the further development. Avoid using .NET class names. For example `Game` instead of `Process`
2. Give methods names which state what the method do e.g. `Game.Run()` instead of `Game.UI()` or `DrawGameBoard` instead of `GameBoard`.
3. Same for variable neames `Random rnd` instead of `Random test`.
4. To introduce OOP make everything non-`static`, then create objects using `new` keyword.
5. A lot of `public` methods which isn't used outside of the class, make it private.
6. Infinite, never ending loop `while(true)`. I suggest to find a way to exit the app.

I'll show some simple example.

Here's implementation via `static`.

```
public class Parent
{
    public static Run()
    {
        Child.Go();
    }

    public static DoCommonJob()
    {
    }
}

public class Child()
{
    public static Go()
    {
        Parent.DoCommonJob();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Parent.Run();
    }
}
```

That's how it looks now.

The following example avoids `static` starting using objects.

```cs
public class Parent
{
    private Child child;

    public Parent()
    {
        child = new Child(this);
    }

    public Run()
    {
        child.Go();
    }

    public DoCommonJob()
    {
    }
}

public class Child()
{
    private Parent parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Go()
    {
        parent.DoCommonJob();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.Run();
    }
}
```

But here's obvious not good solution, cyclic dependency: Parent depends on Child, while Child depends on Parent. It commonly acceptable but can cause problems in future development.

This can be solved by introducing 3rd class where's common method located.

```cs
public class Common
{
    public DoCommonJob()
    {
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    private Child child;
    private Common common;

    public Parent(Common common)
    {
        this.common = new Common();
        this.child = new Child(common);
    }

    public Run()
    {
        child.Go();
    }
}

public class Child()
{
    private Common common;

    public Child(Common common)
    {
        this.common = common;
    }

    public Go()
    {
        common.DoCommonJob();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.Run();
    }
}
```

Both `Parent` and `Child` depends on `Common` while there's no cyclic dependency. Now it looks fine.

Note: `new` keyword creates new instance of the class every time you call it.

For example, this one won't work as expected according to current logic

```cs
while(true)
{
    Game game = new Game();
    game.Run();
}
```

But this one will

```cs
Game game = new Game();
while(true)
{
    game.Run();
}
```

Feel the difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to analyze my code. It is very valuable to me. A question about Part 4: So when do we need to use static methods and members of the class?

Comment: @CarlJohnson for example Singleton pattern implementation `SomeClass.Instance`, named constructors pattern `SomeClass.Create()`, and a lot more useful patterns.

Comment: @CarlJohnson, Static variables/methods belong to the class definition itself. A good example of this is `DateTime.Now`. Non-static variables/methods belong to the objects created from a class definition for instance `var date = new DateTime();  date.AddDays(5);`

Answer (score 2):

in the method `ChangeSnakePosition(int Step, int WhereToWhere)` the variable `WhereToWhere` should not be int, instead you can create enum called Direction

```
public enum Direction
{
    up,
    down,
    left,
    right,
}
```

then the method signature will be

```
ChangeSnakePosition(int Step, Direction direction)
```

this will help in better reading in calling

```
ChangeSnakePosition(Step, -20);
```

instead of a crapy number, it will become a readable value

```
ChangeSnakePosition(Step, Direction.up);
```

---

beside @aepot mentions that you don't have to use static everywhere, your methods should be return what it tries to calculate,
for example in `Process` class the following method

```
void MoveChecks(string wasdMessage, string stepMessage)
```

should return a [tuple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) with direction and steps as following

```
(Direction dir,int step) MoveChecks(string wasdMessage, string stepMessage)
// you should rename this method to be getDirectionFromUser instead of indescribable MoveChecks
```

Then you can safely delete unnecessary property `int userStep` and `string userMove`. The calling will be as following

```
var result = MoveChecks("Enter W S D A", "Put numbers");
Snake.Move(result.dir, result.step);  // to do: don't use statics
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's very valuable to me. 
now I have a clear idea of ​​where I can use enum.